# Enclosure for multiple laptop hard drives?

Tags: hard-drive, enclosures

I have three 2.5" hard drives laying around (500GB, 320GB, 200GB), all SATA. Is there some type of enclosure I can get to stick these in where they are all accessible through one connection? Preferably firewire? (USB would be fine too)

Answer (score 1):

To do it, you'll need a device that supports JBOD (Just a Bunch Of Disks). It's kind off a RAID0, but accepts disks from different sizes.

I don't remember any vendor right now. I think that Western Digital has a sollution that works with JBOD. Iomega also has one, but I don't know if they sell without the disks.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this enclosure from Startech that supports 2.5 and 3.5 SATA drives but it uses eSATA.  Suopports up to five drives.

http://www.startech.com/item/SAT3550ESR-InfoSafe-5-Drive-2535-eSATA-RAID-SATA-HDD-Enclosure.aspx

Link works for me but now reports as repaced with a new SKU

[Updated Enclosure](http://www.startech.com/item/SAT3540ER-35in-4-Drive-eSATA-RAID-External-Hard-Drive-Enclosure-with-Controller.aspx)

Comment: "Product ID does not exist."

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky problem because the drives are different capacities, so I believe aggregating them with RAID0 is not possible (or it would appear as 3 times the lowest capacity drive, 600GB). And it may be difficult to find a triple-drive enclosure, especially one with FireWire. It doesn't really solve your problem, but buying 3 separate FireWire-enabled enclosures may be easier and cheaper, or sharing a single enclosure between the drives may make sense if you only have one FireWire port (and don't want to use a FireWire hub).

Comment: firewire devices can be daisy-chained, so long as each enclosure has a second firewire port.  no need for a hub.

Answer (score 0):

you could use this drive by drive or just get three of them
have never used it so can't vouch for it

[http://www.amazon.com/Vantec-NexStar-NST-D100SU-2-5-Inch-3-5-Inch/dp/B00180MMZC](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00180MMZC)

Answer (score 0):

what about something like [this](http://www.thinkgeek.com/computing/usb-gadgets/a7ea/)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ULTRA Aluminus - Desktop 4 Bay Enclosure - 3.5", USB 3.0, eSATA, JBOD, Black - U12-43130 
http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=8681088&CatId=4269

Comment: You need 3.5" to 2.5" adaptor rails